# Display and appear corectly a pdf file in android

Tags: android, file, pdf

I am trying to open a pdf file in my app. My problem is that i cannot read the document because it appears with weird characters. Also, if i display a txt file, i can read it but the text it's not allign as i want to. All the lines are centerd. My question is what am I doing wrong and how can I correct these mistakes?

My xml

```
<!-- Demonstrates styled string resources.
     See corresponding Java code com.android.sdk.content.StyledText -->
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

and the class

```
public class PrimulAjutor2A extends MainActivity2A
{
    @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       // See assets/res/any/layout/styled_text.xml for this
       // view layout definition.
        setContentView(R.layout.primulajutor2);

        // Programmatically load text from an asset and place it into the
       // text view.  Note that the text we are loading is ASCII, so we
       // need to convert it to UTF-16.
       try {
           InputStream is = getAssets().open("abc.pdf");

            // We guarantee that the available method returns the total
            // size of the asset...  of course, this does mean that a single
           // asset can't be more than 2 gigs.
            int size = is.available();

            // Read the entire asset into a local byte buffer.
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
           is.read(buffer);
            is.close();

           // Convert the buffer into a string.
           String text = new String(buffer);

            // Finally stick the string into the text view.
           TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
            tv.setText(text);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Should never happen!
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }}
```

Comment: use google docs in webview to open your pdf.

Comment: PDF is a binary format, and not convertible to string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use google docs to display your pdf using a webview.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/wv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/> 


</LinearLayout>
```

In your activity class use the following code.

```
       WebView wv= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
     wv.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
     wv.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
     wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
     wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
     wv.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8ZDVNCvRWK8c3YzQVFaWjg1bEU/edit");
```

[image]

Requires user to login to google account and requires permission from the owner of the document. Since you gave me the access i am able to view the same in my phone. Tested on Samsung galaxy S3. WebView can be scrolled and zoomed.

If you have a pdf application installed on your device , you can use intent to provide necessary parameters to open your pdf file.

```
private void openFile(File f, String mimeType)
{
Intent viewIntent = new Intent();
viewIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
viewIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), mimeType);
// using the packagemanager to query is faster than trying startActivity
// and catching the activity not found exception, which causes a stack unwind.
List<ResolveInfo> resolved = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(viewIntent, 0);
if(resolved != null && resolved.size() > 0)
{
    startActivity(viewIntent);
}
else
{
    // notify the user they can't open it.
}
}
```

http://ecestage.googlecode.com/svn-history/r12/branches/src/com/pdfviewer/PdfViewerActivity.java. I haven't tried the code in the link. You can give this a try.

Comment: he can't because he doen't have enough reputation.

Comment: i typed google docs but now it's google drive. i uploaded the pdf there but the url is like this: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8ZDVNCvRWK8c3YzQVFaWjg1bEU/edit. There is no abc.pdf in the link. What should i do?And i'm a girl:D

Comment: you can open google in exactly the same way as above. in webview. If you upload you can get that link. Just do webview.loadUrl("Google drive  with pdf link");

Comment: i've tried for hours to open a pdf file but i failed with brio. The good news is that i found on a site the code that is exactly what i want. However, i have a question: the tutorial says that i need to place the pdf files in emulator's sdcard. When i finish the application i will make an apk and put it on google play. Now, if i place the pdf's on sdcard will still be there after i'll made the sdk? The link is http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/pdf-list-example/ if anyone it's curious

Comment: It requires your phone to have pdf reader application. The same as the  code above. If you have hte pdf reader, replace Uri.fromFile(file) with the path of your pdf file and it should work.

Comment: If your running on emulator, you need to install a pdf reader application manually.